# SQL query word by word of list search in a sentance and it should return the sentaces which has only one value not two or more

Tags: mysql

I have a big list of words (one ID has different values as shown in the table) so I have another table which has ID and sentences having values mentioned in table one so I want the list of sentences which contains only one value not multiple values as shown below:

[image]

Note my both tables are very large so I can check the output carefully.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Below codes should works.

**Instructions:**

1. find out all titles with keywords with same id => `locate(keyword, title)`
2. group by id, category, title, then filter out whose `keyword_found_count`=1

***PS***: table1.keyword=table1.value in your screenshot.

***PS***: next time please put your schemas into the question using `code block` instead of screenshot.

```
select * from (
    select id, category, title, count(case when found>0 then 1 else null end) found_count from (
        select locate(table1.keyword, table2.title) found, table2.id, table2.category, table2.title, table1.keyword
        from table2 left join table1 on table1.id=table2.id
    ) w1 group by id, category, title
) w2 where found_count=1
```

**Output under my environment:**

```
| id | category | title                      | found_count | 
| ---| -------- | -------------------------- | ----------: | 
| 1  | AP       | An Apple Keeps doctor away | 1           | 
| 1  | UP       | I love watermelon          | 1           | 
| 2  | BP       | Most of people like Rabbit | 1           |
```